# Quasar multi fibers warning

Tags: quasar

I am new to quasar and I tried doing this.
Basically I get a warning the fiber is blocking a thread. Why ? can I not do something like below ?

Thanks

```
//in my my testclass I have this
String websites[] = {"http://www.google.com",""http://www.lol.com",""http://www.somenoneexistantwebsite.com"};
            for(int i=0; i < websites.length ; i++){
            TestApp.getWebsiteHTML(websites[i]); 
            }


//in TestApp

     public static void getWebsiteHTML(String webURL) throws IOException, InterruptedException, Exception {
            new Fiber<Void>(new SuspendableRunnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() throws SuspendExecution, InterruptedException {
                WebInfo mywi = new WebInfo();
                mywi.getHTML(webURL);
                }
            }).start().join();
        }        

//in WebInfo
      public static String getHTML(String urlToRead) throws Exception {
          StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
          URL url = new URL(urlToRead);
          HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
          conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
          BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
          String line;
          while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
             result.append(line);
          }
          rd.close();
          return result.toString();
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the "Runaway fibers" sub-section in the [docs](http://docs.paralleluniverse.co/quasar/#fibers).

`HttpURLConnection` is thread-blocking so in order to avoid stealing threads from the fiber scheduler for too much time (which risks killing your Quasar-based application's performance) you should rather use an [HTTP client integrated with Quasar](http://docs.paralleluniverse.co/comsat/#http-clients) (or [integrate one yourself](http://blog.paralleluniverse.co/2014/08/12/noasync/)).